# local server adress link on Mac (switching from Windows)

Tags: macos, lan

I recently switched to Mac from windows.

I have a feature i liked on Windows:

I can have a direct adress to a local server file/folder.

For example, I am chatting with co-worker asking me where is this file, i can go look for it, then after finding it, paste the adress to him like this:

\\nameofserver\folder\clientname\copywriting\content.doc

He would only have to copy and paste this adress in a run box or adress in a explorer windows and that's it.

How to have the equivalent in Mac's Finder ?

1/ copying the local adress
2/ opening this local adress link

I read an other thread that said to use smb: protocol, like
smb://inside/Groups/Company Identity/Office photos/
But it doesnt work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
⌘k
smb://Host/Share/*
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open System Preferences and click "Sharing"
2. Click on File Sharing, and make sure the On checkbox is ticked
3. Select a folder to share using the "+" symbol under "Shared Folders:"
4. On the right side, either select (or add, using the "+" symbol) an account to share the folder under, and the permissions this account has on the folder (Read, Read/Write, etc.)
5. Under the accounts list, click "Options..."
6. Turn on "Share files and folders using SMB" and enable the accounts that can use SMB to access your shared folders
7. When you click "Done", you can close System Preferences
8. Your co-worker can now access your files at: \\YOUR_COMPUTER_NAME\SHARED_FOLDER_NAME on Windows and smb://YOUR_COMPUTER_NAME/SHARED_FOLDER_NAME from OS X

If you would like to turn on the guest account so your co-worker does not need a username/password, please respond and I will walk you through setting up the guest account.